# How to call SOAP web services from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, soap

Is there anyway to call soap web services from angularJS ? is there any service like $http to call SOAP web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick web search came up with this library: https://github.com/andrewmcgivery/angular-soap

Disclaimer: I haven't used the library but looks promising from reading the description:

`An angular port of a Javascript SOAP Client into a factory that has a similar syntax to $http.`

Comment: is this solution is working for you?